# Django.db.utils.IntegrityError. Как правильно указать имя юзера в аргумент поля модели? И как исправить ошибку django.db.utils.IntegrityError?

Tags: python, django, sqlite, model, миграция

Пытаюсь добавить имя юзера в поле name модели Profile.

**models.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Profile(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

После добавления выполняю миграции makemigrations и migrate. Makemigrations выполняется нормально, а после migrate консоль ругается

[image]

Что именно я делаю не так? Как исправить данную ошибку?

> Использую SQlite3, Django 2 версии

Comment: Логи стоит добавлять в виде текста (попройбуте сами прочитать че там написано) и скиньте миграции и настройки INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: @ZaArs По поводу консоли прошу прощения). Сам только что заметил насколько всё мыльно. Данную ошибку я уже исправил тем, что вместо ForeignKey, я поставил OneToOneField. И удалил файлы прошлых миграций(####_auto_########_####.py). И повторил миграции. Ошибка исчезла, но на место неё пришла другая: no such column: firstapp_profile.username_id. Миграции и настройки ещё скидывать?

Comment: Лубые изменения в проблеме стоит фиксировать в вопросе. По вопросу - прверьте наличие миграций `makemigrations` и примените их `migrate`. Если не поможет - очистите БД и повторите (Кто знает, что у вас творится в бд)

Comment: Спасибо большое. Ошибка и правда была в миграциях. Ибо после удаления файлов миграции я не откатывал их. А нужно. Вот сижу и разбираюсь куда нужно вводить delete from django_migrations where app = 'имя приложения'. Для полного удаления миграций.

Comment: @ЭрнстКраузе с консоли подключиться к бд, например и прописать это

Comment: https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/sqlite/connect-to-sqlite-from-the-command-line

Comment: @ДмитрийДмитрук Спасибо вам большое